# Connecting iPhone to HC-05 Bluetooth module

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

I wanted to know how I can connect my iPhone to HC-05 Bluetooth module. Is there any apps for it or/and How can I create an app for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let's see whether anybody knows about any apps for this. If you  need support in creating an app yourself, we can move the question to StackOverflow.com for you which is more suited for development questions (they are off-topic on Ask Different).

Comment: What's wrong with the answer [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153674/connecting-iphone-to-hc-05-bluetooth-module)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they are using different BT profiles so It's not possible. HC-05 is using SPP which iOS does not support.